# If, else in jQuery

Tags: jquery, if-statement

Ok, i have this

```
$("#Tab_Ads").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "_Ajax.AdQuestions.php",
        data: "AdID=<?php echo $_SESSION['SessionAdId']; ?>",
        success: function(data){
        $("#Ads_InfoContent").html(data);
        }   
    });
});
 $("#Tab_Questions").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "_Ajax.AdQuestions.php",
        data: "QuesionID=<?php echo $_SESSION['SessionAdId']; ?>",
        success: function(data){
        $("#Ads_InfoContent").html(data);
        }   
    });
});
```

Now I want display the data in div #Ads_InfoContent by default (before I click #Tab_Questions or else other), how i have to write the condition in jquery to display it? I'm a beginner in jQuery, thank you so much!

Comment: You are just binding the clicks, not executing them. So why would you disable any? Am i understanding it correct: You can only click "#Tab_Questions" if "#Tab_Ads" where clicked first?

Comment: there is no if statement in jquery.

Answer (score 0):

This should trigger the click event as soon as the page has loaded:

```
$("#Tab_Questions").trigger("click");
```

Place this after the click event declaration

Comment: You did it Marius! Thank you all a lot!

Comment: don't forget to set this answer as the Accepted one :)